# Why property binding to the color of a text element is not reactive in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

Below is my .ts file,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-binding',
  templateUrl: './event-binding.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-binding.component.css']
})
export class EventBindingComponent {

  textColor = '';
  onInput = (ev: any) => {
    this.textColor = ev.target.value;
  }
}
```

Below is my HTML template ,

```
<div>
    <h3 [style.color]="textColor">EVENT BINDING</h3>
    <input type="text" (input)="onInput($event)">
</div>
```

Here **when I completely type "blue" in the input box my text color of h3 changes to blue**.
But I noticed **when i press backspace and now the value of textColor is "blu" , the text still remains in Blue color. I was expecting return to black.**
It changes to black only when I clear the entire input.
So is there some kind of history retaining in the color in html? What does this?

Comment: Calling `element.style.color = 're'` or `blu` does not change the element's style, it is ignored. That's why the style doesn't change until the text is back to the empty string.

Comment: Easiest solution: use a dropdown with the names of colors they can pick from. https://htmlcolorcodes.com/color-names/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same happens when maninpulating the DOM with plain JavaScript, I have prepared an example for you:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', event => {
  document.querySelector('h3').style.color = event.target.value;
})
```

```html
<h3>EVENT BINDING</h3>
<input type="text">
```

When trying to set a value which the browser considers as invalid, the operation is not performed. You can see in the DOM that the value of the inline style is not updated. In this case, the last *valid* value will be used. Angular works the same than plain JavaScript here.

As a workaround, you can check whether the entered value is valid with [`CSS.supports()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports), and fall back to black:

```
onInput = (ev: any) => {
  const value = ev.target.value;
  this.textColor = CSS.supports('color', value) ? value : 'black';
}
```

Comment: I wonder why the [code posted by Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75058261/227299) which uses a delayed observable works...

Comment: Why don't you create an example that proposes a solution? An HTML select or clearing the style if the color is not [a valid HTML color](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/color-names/).

Comment: @RuanMendes, Andrew change the color to "none", then change the color with the value. It's the same if:`this.textColor = "";setTimeout(()=>{this.textColor =ev.target.value;})`

Comment: @Eliseo No need for the timeout? That could work but it seems like it needs a lot of comments and it's doing an unnecessary step. I would prefer it to be clear instead of allowing that assumption to seep into the code.

Comment: @RuanMendes thanks for your feedback, I have added a solution to check, whether the entered value is valid.

Comment: @JSON Derulo. I had never heard of`CSS.supports`, this is great! And your username is even cooler 